# InputStream special character UTF-8

Tags: java, utf-8

why this input Stream is not returning the correct Character? Código is turning into C�digo even after a read using UTF-8

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");

        // Starts the query
        conn.connect();
        InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead = stream.read(buffer);
        String page = new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead, "UTF-8");



        //Page is returning, C�digo instead of Código
```

Comment: I solved a similar problem with a encodingfilter (Spring).

Comment: Probably because the server ignored  your "Accept-Charset" preference, and sent the message in a different encoding.

Comment: To account for that, you have to look at the response's `Content-Type` header to know which charset is actually being using. Look at the `conn.getHeaderFieldKey()` and `conn.getHeaderField()` methods to find that header value, then extract its `charset` attribute (or default it if not present) and use that when converting the stream data to String.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Comment: i need api at least 16, and the Standard ask for 19 =(

Answer (score 0):

Solution was:

```
//set the conn to this
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1");

//use Apache Commons IO
            data = IOUtils.toString(stream, "ISO-8859-1");
```

and in the .php page put:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

</head>
...
```